# Binary variance? Comparing two sacks of uneven coins or two heterogenous groups of people

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, variance, sampling, binary-data

I have two sacks of coins. In one sack, the coins are all uniform, each giving a fairly constant 0.5 chance of heads (based on tossing a few of them and also visual inspection). I then estimate the binary variance from the 0.5 success rate. The variance tells me how much I can expect the average success rate in samples to vary due to chance when I sample again and again.

In the other sack, the coins are all bent, uneven. I try a few coins. Some are heavily biased one way, others the other way. Nonetheless, I toss 100 of them in sequence, 1 toss each. The average turns out to be 0.5. Based on that, the estimated binary variance is the same as the sack of uniform coins.

Should we not incorporate our knowledge that a lot of the coins in that sack are heavily biased? Wouldn't we expect a wider margin of error for sampled averages from that sack? Or is it that the average probabilities very quickly average out and we can treat the coins as uniform?

Context for this question: If we are comparing two groups of people on a binary decision task, does it matter that there is a lot of known individual variation between individuals in one or both groups?

I tried doing a simulation where each group was comprised of different sub-populations, each having their own probability of acting a certain way. It didn't seem to make any difference when their behavior was averaged out. Somehow, I was expecting samples of heterogeneous individuals to vary more than samples of homogenous individuals, even when the average behavior is approximately the same in both.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take your example to it's most extreme conclusion and imagine an infinite sack of rigged coins that each magically give a result of either 100% heads or 100% tails.

As long as the chance of drawing one of these perfectly rigged coins is 50/50, we draw a new coin each flip and we have no knowledge of if the coin is rigged or not before drawing, the results in both variance and expected value over time will behave in an identical way to fair coins being flipped over and over again despite the coins being individually completely biased.